# Functions completion handler Swift 4

Tags: swift, function

How i can return error and completion result and call my function like that?
What should i write in my function, to return completion result and error if there are any?

example:

```
signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error)  in
    if error == nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: nil)
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
    }
}
```

my function to edit:

```
static func signIn(email: String, enablefor: String, 
                   func: String, completion: @escaping ((User) -> Void))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it like this:

`completion: @escaping ((User?, Error?) -> Void)`

Inside your function:

`completion(user, nil) // when you have user`

`completion(nil, error) // when you have error`

On the completion block call:

```
completion: { user, error in

    if let error = error {
          // handle error
    }

    if let user = user {
        // handle user
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't suggest underscore characters and parameter labels in the completion closure declaration. This is Swift 2 legacy syntax and pointless in Swift 3+

Comment: can you rephrase that please? Check last edit, is there anything else that you would improve?

Comment: I mean the declaration: `completion: @escaping ((User?, Error?) -> Void)`. The internal and external (`_`) parameter labels are never used in Swift 3+

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare your completion handler to take a tuple as its input argument and make sure you mark both `User` and `Error` parameters as `Optional`, since you should only ever return one of the two.

```
static func signIn(email: String, enablefor: String, func: String, completion: @escaping ((User?,Error?) -> Void))

signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error)  in
    if error == nil, let user = user {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: nil)
    } else {
      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
    }
}
```

You should actually use the `user` parameter, since at the moment you aren't using it for anything.

Comment: Not sure if the parameter name can be `func` though.

Comment: @VladRusu yes it can be and I didn't change that part, OP declared the parameter labels.

Comment: I've seen it in the OP's post too. Didn't try it and never used a keyword as a variable name. For me it just looked strange and personally would avoid it. Didn't know it works..